# gcc.exe Invalid Argument Fatal Error no input files (VScode)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, build

I'm trying to debug my code and am having problems with running the build task. These are the error messages:
[image]

```
Starting build...
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\Sandra study\Documents\2022b\מעבדה C\project maman 14\firstIteration.c" -o "C:\Users\Sandra study\Documents\2022b\מעבדה C\project maman 14\firstIteration.exe"
gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\Sandra study\Documents\2022b\????? C\project maman 14\firstIteration.c: Invalid argument
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

My tasks.json:

[image]
my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn 
    // about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions 
    // of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: 
    // https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname} \\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${Project Maman 14}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I try debugging then I get this error message:
[image]

I'm new to VScode and really don't understand how to use these files any help would be much appreciated